# How to measure site speed in detail?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

Using tools like google analytics or any other load times, it can be measured from different countries, but you really can't know what takes, for example, an image to load or a javascript from cdn, etc...

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit known, but there is an interface in javascript in modern browsers through which you can access this data:

Up here you can meet the different times has a page to load.

Using "**getEntries()**" you can access the load detail of all loaded items, even with partial times.

```
window.performance.getEntries();
```

For example, with a simple calculation, you can know the response time of the server in an element or the main item:

```
var serverResponseSec = (performance.timing.responseStart - performance.timing.navigationStart) / 1000
```

[image]

I put all together in https://metricsmine.com/ to summarize and calculate in detail the time of different elements loaded in different user countries.